# register_post_type and register taxonomy and htaccess

Tags: htaccess, register-taxonomy

I installed a theme called "The Dawn". It supports the addition of new type of post and a taxonomy. Here's the code:

```
register_post_type('portfolio', array(  
    'description' => 'TheDawn Portfolio',
    'show_ui' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/admin/portfolio.png',
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Portfolio',
        'singular_name' => 'Portfolio Item',
        'add_new' => 'Add Portfolio Item',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Portfolio Item',
        'edit' => 'Edit Portfolio Item',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Portfolio Item',
        'new_item' => 'New Portfolio Item',
        'view' => 'View Portfolio Item',
        'view_item' => 'View Portfolio Item',
        'search_items' => 'Search Portfolio Items',
        'not_found' => 'No Portfolio Items found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Portfolio Items found in Trash',
        'parent' => 'Parent Portfolio Item',
    ),
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'author', 'page-attributes'),
    'public' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => false,
    //'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => true),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag' ),
    ) 
);

register_taxonomy( 'portfolios', 'portfolio', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Portfolio Categories', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => false ) );
```

This works fine ... but I do not know what to put in the htaccess. Indeed, base, there is no url rewriting (`rewrite => false`). So I have URLs like this: my-site /?portfolio=my-item.

I find it very ugly. So I forced rewrite (`rewrite => true`): urls are generated my-site/portfolios/my-item. Except that now, if I click on my menu ... Wordpress generates 404.

I guess I need to change the htaccess. What should I put?

thank you

Comment: Try going to your settings-->permalinks and hitting "Save" . WordPress is not aware of the code change you made until it refreshes the permalinks.

Comment: @Wyck +1... Go to permalinks and hit save. This will solve your 404 issue.

Comment: Yes, it works ! Thank you ! Create a answer and I vote for you =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going to your settings-->permalinks and hitting "Save" . WordPress is not aware of the code change you made until it refreshes the permalinks.

Adding this^ so you can close this Question.